# Mapstruct list of object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to write DocumentMapper or I can write specifically secs to sections or I can how to do it here. Can I also write SectionMapper or can I combine everything I want to add into DucumentMapper?

```
public class Body {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "sec")
    private List<Sec> secs;

}
public class Sec {

@XmlElement(name = "title")
private String title;

@XmlElement(name = "p")
private List<String> ps;

@XmlElement(name = "sec")
private List<Sec> subsections;

@XmlElement(name = "fig")
private List<String> figs;

}

public class Document extends JPAEntity {

@NonNull
@Column(name = "name", length=2000)
private String name;

@Column(name = "status", length=50)
private String status;

private List<Section> sections;

}

public class Section extends JPAEntity {

private String title;

private List<Paragraph> paragraphs;

private List<Figure> figures;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes thanks, I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface SectionMapper {
 
SectionMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( SectionMapper.class );
 
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "title", target = "title"),
    @Mapping(source = "ps", target = "paragraphs"),
    @Mapping(source = "figs", target = "figures")
})
Section secToSection(Sec sec);

List<Section> map(List<Sec> list);

List<Section> convertSecDTOListToSectionList(List<Sec> list);

List<Sec> convertSectionListToSecDTOList(List<Section> list);


@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "p", target = "paragraph")
})
Paragraph pToParagraph(String p);   

    
List<Paragraph> convertPsDTOListToParagraphList(List<String> list);



@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "fig", target = "figure")
})
Figure figToFigure(String fig);  

List<Figure> convertFigsDTOListToFigureList(List<String> list);

}
```

Don't forget getter/setter method